# Unit test seems not to trigger RxJS stream

Tags: angular, jestjs, rxjs

Here is my test:

```
  it( 'should drop element', ( done ) => {

    component.media.init$.pipe(
      filter( isInit => !!isInit ),
      take( 1 ),
      tap( _ => {

        console.log('hello')

        fixture.detectChanges();

        const dNDDirective = fixture.debugElement.query( By.directive( DnDClipDirective ) );

        ( dNDDirective.componentInstance as DnDClipDirective ).drop$.emit( {
          event:<Event>{
            target:{}
          },
          files:[{
            audio:new ArrayBuffer(0),
            url:'test',
            filename:'test'
          }]
        });

        component.filesService.isDragFromTree = true;

        component.filesService.draggedFile = { audio:new ArrayBuffer( 0 ), url:'test', filename:'test' };

        const spyObj = jest.spyOn( component.media, 'dropAudioElements' );

        expect( spyObj ).toHaveBeenCalledTimes( 1 )

        expect( component.filesService.files ).toHaveLength( 1 );

        done()

        console.log( "HELLO 2")

      } )
    ).subscribe()

    console.log('HELLO')

    component.media.init$.next( true );

  }, 6000 )
```

The `done` is never triggered and I get a timeout error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unclear without looking at the source, but you can remove `take` maybe that is why the subscribe isn't working ( if `init$` is a behaviour subject then `take` might ignore the second emit! ), also can you remove the `,6000` at the end, am unsure what that one does!

```
 it( 'should drop element', ( done ) => {    
    component.media.init$.pipe(
      filter( isInit => !!isInit ),
      tap( _ => {
        console.log('hello')
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const dNDDirective = fixture.debugElement.query( By.directive( DnDClipDirective ) );
        ( dNDDirective.componentInstance as DnDClipDirective ).drop$.emit( {
          event:<Event>{
            target:{}
          },
          files:[{
            audio:new ArrayBuffer(0),
            url:'test',
            filename:'test'
          }]
        });
        component.filesService.isDragFromTree = true;
        component.filesService.draggedFile = { audio:new ArrayBuffer( 0 ), url:'test', filename:'test' };
        const spyObj = jest.spyOn( component.media, 'dropAudioElements' );
        expect( spyObj ).toHaveBeenCalledTimes( 1 );
        expect( component.filesService.files ).toHaveLength( 1 );
        done();
        console.log( "HELLO 2");
      })
    ).subscribe()
    console.log('HELLO')
    component.media.init$.next( true );
  })
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not working the first init value is set to false te true this is why I've added a take 1 if you need more details lease let me know.

Comment: sorry looks like it's working but knwo the By.directive not retrieving any componentInstance.Any idea?

Comment: @JSmith have you imported/declared the main component and the directive, also try fixture.detectChanges before and after, component also needs to be initialized before it runs!